# How to use python ebaysdk to filter items from a multi variation listing (listing of more than one item)

Tags: python, ebay-api, ebay-sdk

When I use the python finding sdk to search for listings with eBay, I usually get results that include a listing containing two or more items that I am not searching for. An example:

```
request1 = {
        'keywords': "Iphone x 64gb", # I am searching for Listings of an iPhone x 64gb
        'itemFilter': [
            {'name': 'Condition', 'value': 'Used'},
            {'name': 'currency', 'value': 'CAD'},
            {'name': 'minPrice', 'value': 100.0}
        ],
        'paginationInput': {
            'entriesPerPage': 100,
            'pageNumber': 13
        },
        'sortOrder': 'BestMatch'
}

 api = find_connect(config_file='ebay.yml',  siteid="EBAY-ENCA")
 resp = api.execute('FindPopularItems', request1).dict() # Change from XML to dictionary
 parse_response(reps) # send the dictionary of listings to be parsed
```

When I look at some of the listings that have been returned from the API request, I can get something like this

```
itemId: 303279232871
title: Apple iPhone X Smartphone 64GB 256GB AT&T Sprint T-Mobile Verizon or Unlocked
globalId: EBAY-US
subtitle: 30-Day Warranty - Free Charger & Cable - Easy Returns!
primaryCategory: {'categoryId': '9355', 'categoryName': 'Cell Phones & Smartphones'}
galleryURL: https://thumbs4.ebaystatic.com/pict/303279232871404000000001_2.jpg
viewItemURL: https://www.ebay.ca/itm/Apple-iPhone-X-Smartphone-64GB-256GB-AT-T-Sprint-T-Mobile-Verizon-Unlocked-/303279232871?var=602277420740
paymentMethod: PayPal
autoPay: true
postalCode: 660**
location: USA
country: US
shippingInfo: {'shippingServiceCost': {'_currencyId': 'CAD', 'value': '23.83'}, 'shippingType': 'Flat', 'shipToLocations': 'Worldwide'}
sellingStatus: {'currentPrice': {'_currencyId': 'USD', 'value': '309.0'}, 'convertedCurrentPrice': {'_currencyId': 'CAD', 'value': '436.46'}, 'sellingState': 'Active', 'timeLeft': 'P21DT20H28M35S'}
listingInfo: {'bestOfferEnabled': 'false', 'buyItNowAvailable': 'false', 'startTime': '2019-09-09T14:07:31.000Z', 'endTime': '2020-05-09T14:07:31.000Z', 'listingType': 'FixedPrice', 'gift': 'false', 'watchCount': '18'}
galleryPlusPictureURL: https://galleryplus.ebayimg.com/ws/web/303279232871_1_3459_1_00000001.jpg
condition: {'conditionId': '2500', 'conditionDisplayName': 'Seller refurbished'}
isMultiVariationListing: true # **This means that it is a multi variation listing**
topRatedListing: false
```

This is a listing of an Iphone x 64gb and 256gb which have different prices. There may even be more than 2 items with different prices (a customer might want to but it used or new, etc). However, I do not just want to discard it from my dataset as eBay's API only returns 10000 listings at maximum and only allows 5000 calls a day (the data is still relevant). 
How may I filter each separate item from the listing?

Answer (score 0):

One thing I can think of that should help is if you query by aspect instead of using keyword. The example below looks for "iphone x" results with "64 GB" of storage. Aspect filtering must be done within the appropriate category. This also assumes the seller has created the listing with the structured data.

```
api_request = {
    'keywords': "Iphone x", 
    'itemFilter': [
        {'name': 'Condition', 'value': 'Used'},
        {'name': 'currency', 'value': 'CAD'},
        {'name': 'minPrice', 'value': 100.0}
    ],
    'aspectFilter': [
        {
            'aspectName': 'Storage Capacity',
            'aspectValueName': '16 GB',
        }
    ],
    'categoryId': 9355,
    'outputSelector': [
        'AspectHistogram',
    ],
    'paginationInput': {
        'entriesPerPage': 100,
        'pageNumber': 1
    },
    'sortOrder': 'BestMatch'
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this solution remove all listings that are multi-variation? Usually, multi-variation listings are made by reputable sellers meaning that I would be leaving out relevant data. Is there a way to extract each item's data out of the multi-variation?

Comment: I think there's a problem with the API because the aspectFilter just made things worse. When I run the code with the aspectFilter, not only do I still get multivariate listings,all I get is a list of "iPhone 6" items instead of "iPhone x"